# How to run composer update command after code deploy on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I have setup Code Deploy service on aws and It's working great, but what I want is to run `composer update` command after deploying.

I have defined `composer update` command in AfterInstall hook, but It doesn't seem to work.

Here's my appspec.yml

```php
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /var/www/laravel/
hooks:
  AfterInstall:
    - location: hooks/after-install.sh
      runas: root
```

and here's the after-install.sh file code:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

php /var/www/laravel/artisan clear-compiled
php /var/www/laravel/artisan optimize
php /var/www/laravel/artisan view:clear
php /var/www/laravel/artisan cache:clear

chown -R ubuntu:www-data /var/www/laravel
sudo find /var/www/laravel -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +
sudo find /var/www/laravel -type f -exec chmod 644 {} +
chmod -R 777 /var/www/laravel/storage

composer update
```

all other commands work except the composer update, any help is appreciated.

Thakns

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your original question but you shouldn't run `composer update`, instead bundle the `composer.lock` file with your project and run `composer install`. That way you make sure that you always get the same dependencies across your environments.

Comment: @KarlLaurentiusRoos I tried to run `composer install` as well, but that didn't work too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must include absolute path for the directory where your project resides (where you have `composer.json` file for the dependencies).

Replace `composer update` with `composer update -d /var/www/laravel`

and It will work like charm.